# Integrating $\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} t^{x} e^{x t} dx$ where $t>0$ and $s>0$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This question is an offspring of the question
[A closed form for: $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x-\log x)^2}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277690/a-closed-form-for-int-0-infty-frac1x-log-x2dx/3298266#3298266)

In amongst the comments and incomplete answers to this question, a conjecture was raised on the equivalence between two different generalized definite integrals for real $p \ge 2$, that is
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{(x-\log (x))^p} \, dx=  \frac{ 1}{\Gamma(p)} {\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{x^{x-p+2}} \, dx}\tag{1}$$

In an attempt to prove this I have noted the known result

$$\int_0^\infty t^b e^{-a t} \,dt=\frac{\Gamma(b+1)}{a^{b+1}}\tag{2}$$

proved by integration by parts multiple times in the case of integer $b$
(see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Applications)

By utilizing (2) and changing the order of integration on the r.h.s. of (1) I was led to the following conjecture for $t>0$ and $s>0$

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} t^{x} e^{-x t} \,dx=\frac{1}{(t-\log(t))^s}$$

Mathematica 12.0 manages to calculate this integral quite happily, but I'm none the wiser how it solves this, even in the case of integer values of $s$. Any ideas or relevant references for solution of integrals of this kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(2)$ is proven simply by substitution $t=x/a$ and the definition of $\Gamma(b+1)$.

Your last formula is an application of this, as $t^x e^{-xt}=e^{-(t-\log(t))x}$.

Comment: @James: I would like to proof, following the way of [Sasha](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334775/strategy-for-improper-integrals-related-to-the-beta-function-2/334936#334936) using the 
Plancherel theorem. This should work, but I have not the time. I suggest you to try this way.