# Closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+k)!(a/n)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, gamma-function

I got this equality:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+k)!\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)^n=a(k+1)!\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+ax\ln x)^{k+2}}$$

when $|a|<e$

then, does this series have a closed form?

Comment: I don't think so. (Somewhat [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3277690), and an amusingly [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Integer_and_complex_powers) series...)